# Как подписаться на событие, используя обработчик с другой сигнатурой?

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как в коде С# подписаться на событие MouseDown3D с методом обработки, принимающим в качестве второго параметра MouseDown3DEventArgs, а не RoutedEventArgs:

```
public SelectHelper3D(IDrawingEngine3D drawingEngine)
    {
        _drawingEngine = drawingEngine;

        _drawingEngine.Viewport.MouseDown3D += ViewportMouseDown3D;
    }

    private void ViewportMouseDown3D(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Пример:

```
<hx:Viewport3DX
        x:Name="view1"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Camera="{Binding Camera}"
        CoordinateSystemLabelForeground="White"
        EffectsManager="{Binding EffectsManager}"
        ShowCoordinateSystem="True"
        SubTitle="{Binding SubTitle}"
        TextBrush="Black"
        UseDefaultGestures="False">
        <hx:Viewport3DX.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="B" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.BackView" />
            <KeyBinding Key="F" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.FrontView" />
            <KeyBinding Key="U" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.TopView" />
            <KeyBinding Key="D" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.BottomView" />
            <KeyBinding Key="L" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.LeftView" />
            <KeyBinding Key="R" Command="hx:ViewportCommands.RightView" />
            <KeyBinding Command="hx:ViewportCommands.ZoomExtents" Gesture="Control+E" />
            <MouseBinding Command="hx:ViewportCommands.Rotate" Gesture="RightClick" />
            <MouseBinding Command="hx:ViewportCommands.Zoom" Gesture="MiddleClick" />
            <MouseBinding Command="hx:ViewportCommands.Pan" Gesture="Shift+RightClick" />
        </hx:Viewport3DX.InputBindings>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown3D">
                <ie:CallMethodAction MethodName="OnMouseDown3DHandler" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

 public void OnMouseDown3DHandler(object sender, MouseDown3DEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.HitTestResult != null && e.HitTestResult.ModelHit is MeshGeometryModel3D meshGeometryModel3D && (meshGeometryModel3D.Geometry == Model || meshGeometryModel3D.Geometry == Model2))
        {
            Target = null;
            CenterOffset = meshGeometryModel3D.Geometry.Bound.Center; // Must update this before updating target
            Target = (Element3D) e.HitTestResult.ModelHit;
        }
    }
```

Здесь я вообще не понимаю, как работает CallMethodAction, принимая в качестве обработчика метод с другим параметром.

Событие реализовано следующим образом:

```
 public event RoutedEventHandler MouseDown3D
    {
        add { this.AddHandler(GeometryModel3D.MouseDown3DEvent, value); }
        remove { this.RemoveHandler(GeometryModel3D.MouseDown3DEvent, value); }
    }
```

[helix-toolkit:source code](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/blob/develop/Source/HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX/Controls/Viewport3DX.Properties.cs)

Comment: В примере же все написано.

Comment: В примере это сделано с помощью interactivity в Xaml, а мне надо это сделать в классе c#.

Comment: Сделайте "прокладку", т.е. подпишите событие на метод с нужными событию параметрами, а из нее вызовите метод (преобразовав параметры) тот который нужен вам. Возможно  "interactivity в Xaml" умеет сам генерировать "прокладки", ну а чистый с# не умеет.

Comment: @nick_n_a Спасибо))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
private void ViewportMouseDown3D(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       OnMouseDown3DHandler(sender, e as MouseDown3DEventArgs);
    }

    public void OnMouseDown3DHandler(object sender, MouseDown3DEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HitTestResult != null && e.HitTestResult.ModelHit is MeshGeometryModel3D meshGeometryModel3D)
        {

        }
    }
```